# How do you set Access-Control-Allow-Origin on Firebase files

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` on a certain file.

This is my firebase.json file:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "headers": [ {
    "source" : "bundle.js",
    "headers" : [ {
      "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "value" : "*"
    } ]
  }]
}
```

However it never gets set: https://curious-athlete-131013.firebaseapp.com/bundle.js

Answer (score 5):

Try nesting the headers underneath hosting rather than as it's own top level node:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [{
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
    }],
    "headers": [{
      "source" : "bundle.js",
      "headers" : [{
        "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value" : "*"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

"Custom, file specific, headers can be specified by defining a headers section **within hosting** in the firebase.json file:" - [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites)